# Django 2.2 Cannot figure out how to authorize user to edit or delete blog post if user created that blog post

Tags: python, django

So this is the third time I'm asking this question. I don't know how to allow only a user, that created a particular blog post, to edit or delete that post. So this blog is like any other blog. All users can look at all other users blog posts. To create a blog post, a user must be logged in with an account already. Same thing for edit and delete a blog post. However, I don't know how to check to see if a user can edit or delete a blog post based off whether that user was the one that created the blog post or not. I'm typing this question since no one answered my previous questions I posted. below are three files for models, views, and the html for update/edit a blog post. I can figure out the delete once I figure out the edit. I know Django creates add, change, delete permissions automatically. Unfortunately, the change and delete permissions always return false, even if that user is already logged in. I've been stuck on this for days. Like 15+ hours already over three days.

blog/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db.models import Q

User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL

class BlogPostQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def published(self):
        now = timezone.now()
        return self.filter(publish_date__lte=now)

    def search(self, query):
        lookup = (
            Q(title__icontains=query) |
            Q(content__icontains=query) |
            Q(slug__icontains=query) |
            Q(user__first_name__icontains=query) |
            Q(user__last_name__icontains=query) |
            Q(user__username__icontains=query) |
            Q(user__email__icontains=query) |
            Q(image__icontains=query)
        )
        return self.filter(lookup)

class BlogPostManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return BlogPostQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

    def published(self):
        return self.get_queryset().published()

    def search(self, query=None):
        if query is None:
            return self.get_queryset().none()
        return self.get_queryset().published().search(query)

class BlogPost(models.Model): # blogpost_set -> queryset
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='image/', blank=True, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True) # Example: "hello world" -> hello-world
    content = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    publish_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null=True, blank=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    objects = BlogPostManager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-publish_date','-updated','-timestamp']
        permission = (
            ("can_change_blogpost", "Can change BlogPost"),        
        )

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return f"/blog/{self.slug}"

    def get_edit_url(self):
        return f"{self.get_absolute_url()}/edit"

    def get_delete_url(self):
        return f"{self.get_absolute_url()}/delete"
```

blog/views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import BlogPost
from .forms import BlogPostModelForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


def blog_post_list_view(request):
    qs = BlogPost.objects.all().published() # queryset -> list of python objects
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        my_qs = BlogPost.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        qs = (qs | my_qs).distinct()
    context = {'object_list':qs}
    return render(request, 'blog/list.html', context)

@login_required
def blog_post_create_view(request):
    form = BlogPostModelForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.user = request.user
        obj.save()
        form = BlogPostModelForm()
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'blog/form.html', context)

def blog_post_detail_view(request, slug):
    obj = get_object_or_404(BlogPost, slug=slug)
    context = {'object':obj}
    return render(request, 'blog/detail.html', context)

@login_required
def blog_post_update_view(request, slug):
    obj = get_object_or_404(BlogPost, slug=slug)
    form = BlogPostModelForm(request.POST or None, instance=obj)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
    context = {
            "form":form,
            "title":f"Update {obj.title}",
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/update.html', context)

@login_required
def blog_post_delete_view(request, slug):
    obj = get_object_or_404(BlogPost, slug=slug)
    if request.method == "POST":
        obj.delete()
    context = {'object':obj}
    return render(request, 'blog/delete.html', context)
```

blog/templates/blog/update.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'blog/style.css' %}">
    <title>New Blog post</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="parallax5" align="center">
        <h1 class="a">UPDATE your Blog page</h1><br>
        <h1>Perms</h1><br>
        {{ perms.blog.change_blogpost }}<br>
        {% if perms.blog.change_blogpost %}
        <form style="background-color:grey;" method="POST" action=".">
            <p>Please only post blogs that are in good taste. You can 
            update your blog below.</p>
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <button type="submit">Update Blog</button>
        </form><br>
        {% else %}
            <p style="background-color:red;color:white;">You do not have permission to update this blog post</p>
        {% endif %}
        <a style="background-color:white;font-size:50px;" href="{% url 'list' %}">I'm done!<br>Go back to blog list</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

WHAT I'VE TRIED SO FAR...
Everything! You name it, I already (very highly likely) know what you're talking about. I'm too tired and angry to even go over the big list of everything I've tried. Please someone help!

Comment: Django's default permissions are designed for table-level access so I wouldn't use those for row-level. In your edit and delete views I would use `obj = get_object_or_404(BlogPost, slug=slug, user=request.user)` so if the user didn't create the blog post they get a 404.

Answer (score 1):

My site does have exactly the same behaviour you're asking for but with quite the different implementation.

Post Delete View looks like this:

```
class PostDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Post
    success_url = '/market'

    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.author:
            return True
        return False
```

Post Update View:

```
class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'content']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.author:
            return True
        return False
```

for this code to work you would also need to import these:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin
from django.views.generic import ( ListView, DetailView, CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView)
```

I know, just showing you my code base might not help you directly but it might give you some ideas, let me know. And stay strong, I know it can get frustrating sometimes, but you will manage it.